# Prove that $f(t)=(A_{11}-t)(A_{22}-t)\cdots(A_{nn}-t)+q(t)$ where $q(t)$ is a polynomial of degree atmost $n-2$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a $n*n$ matrix with characteristic polynomial $f(t)= (-1)^n t^n + a_{n-1} t^{n-1} + \cdots + a_1 t + a_0.$ Prove that $f(t)=(A_{11}-t)(A_{22}-t) \cdots (A_{nn}-t)+q(t)$ where $q(t)$ is a polynomial of degree atmost $n-2$.

The hint says to use mathematical induction.How do i proceed?

Comment: There should be some simpler solution. Do you know an explicit formula for $a_{n-1}$?

Comment: @edm no i dont.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The coefficient $a_{n-1}$ of the characteristic polynomial $f(t) = \det(tI -A)$ is $(-1)^{n-1} \operatorname{tr}(A)$ as can be seen by a direct calculation. Hence, the coefficients of $t^n, t^{n-1}$ for $f(t)$ and $(A_{11} -t) \cdots (A_{nn} - t)$ are identical so their difference is a polynomial whose degree is at most $n - 2$.